# How to install python crypto library on redshift

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-redshift

I need to do `AES` encryption and `AES` Decryption on `redshift`.

My code for encryption and decryption is running successsfully on my local system. However, after creating library of same code on `redshift` I am getting the following error:

> Amazon Invalid operation: ImportError: No module named
>   Crypto.Cipher. Please look at svl_udf_log for more information.

Please help, how I can add crypto library on `redshift` database.

I have followed the following steps:

**Step 1:**
Create a file AESEncrypt.py, code mentioned below.

```
class AESEncrypt(object):
    iv = '1111111111111111'

    def __init__(self):
        self.bs = AES.block_size

    def encrypt(self, raw, key):
        raw = self._pad(raw)
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, self.iv)
        return base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(raw))

    def decrypt(self, enc, key):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, self.iv)
        return self._unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc)).decode('utf-8')

    def _pad(self, s):
        return s + (self.bs - len(s) % self.bs) * chr(self.bs - len(s) % self.bs)

    @staticmethod
    def _unpad(s):
        return s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]


'''
# Testing Code
key = 'my_test_key_0001'
data = 'my_test_data'

aes =  AESEngine()
encString = aes.encrypt(data, key)
print encString

decString = aes.decrypt(encString, key)
print decString
'''
```

Encryption decryption with this code working.

**Step 2:**
Created a zip file (my_functions.zip) with code and created a library on redshift

```
create library all_functions 
language plpythonu 
from 's3://my-bucket/my_functions.zip'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=my_aws_access_key_id ;aws_secret_access_key=my_aws_secret_access_key'
region as 'my_region';
```

**Step 3:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AES_ENCRYPT (originalVal varchar, key varchar)
RETURNS VARCHAR
STABLE
AS $$
  from my_functions.crypto.AESEncrypt import AESEncrypt
  return AESEncrypt().encrypt(originalVal,key)       
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu
;
```

**Step 4:**

```
select AES_ENCRYPT('my_test_data','my_test_key_0001');
```

> Amazon Invalid operation: ImportError: No module named
>   Crypto.Cipher. Please look at svl_udf_log for more information
>   Details:   -----------------------------------------------   error: 
>   ImportError: No module named Crypto.Cipher. Please look at svl_udf_log
>   for more information   code:      10000   context:   UDF   query:
>   0   location:  udf_client.cpp:369   process:   padbmaster [pid=16635] 
>   -----------------------------------------------; [SQL State=XX000, DB Errorcode=500310] 1 statement failed.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to explain the steps you took, so that we can try to reproduce the situation? I presume you created a library for a stored procedure, so please include those steps, plus where you obtained the crypto library.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for looking, I have mentioned the steps I followed. I have many other Python files in the same packages which are not using Crypto and  I am successfully able to use them in Redshift.

Comment: Does your zip file include the `crypto` package?

Comment: yes, my python file (AESEncrypt.py) is written in a package named crypto

Comment: But the `crypto` library is not a standard part of Python. You would need to include it in a library file. Did you include the `crypto` package in your zip file? Can you tell us what is in your zip file so we can try to reproduce your situation?

Comment: My zip package contains a package named `crypto` and some files like `AESEncrypt.py, X.py, Y.py` etc. I think I got your point, I need to download crypto and include it in my library. Please suggest if I am right. Sorry for silly questions, actually new in python.

Comment: I suspect you will need to create a library called Crypto, since the error message says it is seeking `Crypto.Cipher`. Start by adding it to your zip. If that doesn't work, create a separate library for it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have done the AES encryption as mentioned in https://github.com/ksiddiqui79/redshift_udfs/tree/master/encrypt_decrypt_udf/using_pyaes. Thanks for your time.